# Android - Slow ProgressDialog with webservice AsyncTask

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

i have a problem. I have an asynctask, in which i connect to a web service, bring data and put it in a database. Thats ok, it works.  But i have a problem, i want to put a progress bar after i click REFRESH (thats when i do the web service)..

When i refresh, it takes 2 seconds while my screen is freezed and after that starts the progressbar a little and then dissapear, but the taks is done before the progressbar starts.

Here is the code of the asynctask

```
private class tareaActualizar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
         private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "actualizo";
         private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ShamanOperativoActivity.this);

         @Override
         protected void onCancelled() {
             Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onCancelled");

                 pd.dismiss();

         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onPostExecute");

                 pd.dismiss();

         }

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {

             pd.setMessage("Actualizando...");
             pd.show();


         }

         @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {



         }
         @Override
         protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


            webService();

             tv2 = resultado.toString();            //Obtengo el string resultado del WebService en tv2

             //Obtengo la hora actual

             insertoEnBD(); 
             // Inserto en base de datos (Si es que pase por el Web Service)
             Boolean res = true;
            return res;



         }







     }
```

Webservice is the method of the conection of webservice, and "InsertoBD" is when i put data into database.. thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your AsyncTask implementation, How do you know your task finished before progress bar started. according to your description, apart from the 2 seconds freeze, I would say it is what I expected from your AsyncTask: progress bar showing -> task finished quickly -> progress bar dismissed.

Comment: cause my ui is refreshed and changes data.. and after i see that the progressbar starts ..

Comment: I would suggest comment out all code in doInBackground(), and simply do a Log.i(TAG, "do something") to see if the UI refresh is actually from your doInBackground(). by doing this, you can also check in Logcat to see if doInBackground() is called after onPreExecute(). I guess there may be somewhere else in your code doing the same heavy task in main thread, that explains the 2 second freeze when click refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way you instantiate your ProgressDialog to this:

```
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         pd  = ProgressDialog.show( context, "", "My text is here..." );
     }
```

Note, that if you only use the emulator for testing, ProgressDialogs can be slow in appearing/disappearing meaning your problem might not exist if you test on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to declare the ProgressDialog in your environment Activity. And then you can try this code. It works for me:

Environment class where AsyncTask is declared:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

...

private class tareaActualizar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
         private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "actualizo";

...
@Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {

                    pd = new ProgressDialog(ShamanOperativoActivity.this);

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(getParent().getParent(), "Wait",
                    "Loading...");


         }
...
```

Comment: i cant understand this, i declare dialog in my class, and then i use pd in my asynctask class?  i tried this code and it shows a force close by nullpointer exception..

Comment: You have to place both classes in the same .java file.

Answer (score 0):

Try these one .....

```
private class tareaActualizar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 

{

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "actualizo";

         private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ShamanOperativoActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
              pd.setMessage("Actualizando...");
             pd.show();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... para) {

              webService();

             tv2 = resultado.toString();            //Obtengo el string resultado del WebService en tv2

             //Obtengo la hora actual

             insertoEnBD(); 
             // Inserto en base de datos (Si es que pase por el Web Service)
             Boolean res = true;
            return res;


        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {

              pd.dismiss();

        }
    }
```